# Can Confluence show all inline comments on a page?

Tags: comments, confluence

It is easy to lose inline comments on a page because you have to notice the very light yellow highlight on text. Yet, inline comments are invaluable in a collaborative environment.

Is there a way to reveal all inline comments in Confluence, similar to Microsoft Word's track changes, or Google Documents comments view?

Answer (score 6):

According to [this Atlassian Answers question](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/12272669/how-to-see-all-comments-to-a-confluence-page), there is no built-in way to do so.

So I built a JavaScript function which you can easily turn into a bookmarklet using a service like Bookmarklet Crunchinator. It iterates through comments in a page, and allows you to stop iterating when you've reached a comment you wish to read or further discuss.

```
ics = document.getElementsByClassName("inline-comment-marker valid");
for (var i = 0, len = ics.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(ics[i]);
    ics[i].click();
    ics[i].scrollIntoView(true);
    currentMsg = "Current: " + ics[i].textContent + "\nNext?";
    if (!confirm(currentMsg)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My cheap workaround (which might not work in all situations) is to add a "dummy" comment at the top of the page, and then I can use that as the starting point for going through all unresolved comments.